# add button(s) to a kendo-ui panelbar item

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I would like ta dd buttons in a kendo-panelbar-item.
Is that possible?

```
<kendo-panelbar>
    <kendo-panelbar-item title="Heroes" >
                <kendo-panelbar-item  *ngFor="let hero of heroes" title={{hero.name}} >

                //add buttons here

                </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not template but ng-template

```html
 <ng-template kendoPanelBarContent>
              <button kendoButton>Button</button>
 </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a problem with adding buttons inside the PanelBar item.

```
<kendo-panelbar>
        <kendo-panelbar-item title="My Teammates" expanded="true">
            <template kendoPanelBarContent>
                <button kendoButton>Button</button>
            </template>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar>
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zsV7WNOkTspHSL0MN5q2?p=preview)

Comment: I was not using the latest version of kendo-layout. After updating and implementing your code works.
I have updated this plunkr, question is can I add a button on the next to the hero.name?
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tu9kZRjca9YC1dz6lYlZ?p=preview

Comment: such functionality will be implemented as part of this issue: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/85